# How to select text node in DOM using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="main">17.00<span>%</span></div>
```

I would like to select the `17.00` portion but it's not working when I use `$('#id:first-child').html();`. How can I select it?

Comment: Wouldn't say this is a duplicate. This question: getting a single, well specified text node, explicitly *excluding* a neighbor node's text contents. The linked [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery) is asking for *all* text node descendants, recursively. This question and the top answer solved it for me.

Answer (score 8):

jQuery doesn't give much to work directly with text nodes, so you could do it like this:

```
$('#main')[0].firstChild
```

The `[0]` gets the first DOM element from the jQuery object, and uses the native `firstChild` property to get the text node.

To get the text content of the node, add `.data` or `.nodeValue`.

```
$('#main')[0].firstChild.data;      // 17.00
$('#main')[0].firstChild.nodeValue; // 17.00
```

---

An alternate way would be...

```
$('#main')[0].childNodes[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't help much with text nodes.  You can get the "17.00" text with this javascript:

```
var text = document.getElementById("main").firstChild.nodeValue;
```

If you really wanted to use jQuery (though there's no reason that I'm aware of), you could do this:

```
var text = $("#main").get(0).firstChild.nodeValue;
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/EAwCB/