# Javascript removing the last occurence

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <a title="Go to Page." href="http://www.domain.com/dev" class="home">Home Page</a> &gt; <a title="Go to the News category archives." href="http://www.domain.com/dev"/topics/news/" class="taxonomy category">News</a> &gt; <span>News</span>
</div>
```

In the above example there are 2 seperators, I'm using the following `jQuery('.breadcrumbs .category').remove();` to remove the link to the News but this leaves me with

```
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <a title="Go to Page." href="http://www.domain.com/dev" class="home">Home Page</a> &gt; &gt; <span>News</span>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to remove one of the `&gt;`?

Comment: try regular expressions

Comment: @Hawk: I hope that's a joke.

Comment: regular expressions are very powerful indeed, don't underestimate them.

Comment: @Donald: Why do you want to remove the middle `News` element?

Comment: @Hawk: I know what they are capable of, but they're the wrong tool for [this job](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi a plugin I am using gives the `<a>` while on the News page so I wanted to just remove it

Comment: What's generating the breadcrumb links? Wouldn't it be better to modify *that*?

Comment: @Donald: Can't you fix that plugin instead of messing with its output client-side? Is `/News` the only page where this happens or should it be more generic?

Comment: @Bergi he wants to remove the &gt, one of them so it is possible as long as you can get inside using DOM

Comment: @Hawk: Yes, you can get it via the DOM more easily than writing an error-prone regex

Comment: when you get it through the DOM, you would still write a regex to remove only one of the &gt.

Comment: @Hawk: please post an answer that uses regex, rather than a series of comments defending their use. I think they're the wrong tool, as does Bergi, it seems. But if you feel they're correct that's your call.

Comment: Maybe you can select only what you need and replace the whole thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select text node in DOM with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598701/how-to-select-text-node-in-dom-using-jquery)

Comment: I just added an answer using Regex, it is the right tool here, since he wants to replace double `gt;` text with single `gt;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would be the best way to remove one of the `&gt;`?

To fix the plugin that generates it (and the `News` link) in the first place.

> What would be the easiest way to remove it via JavaScript?

This will do it:

```
jQuery('.breadcrumbs .category').each(function() {
    $([this, this.nextSibling]).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't worry about removing the last occurrence, use css to place the (presentational) `>` in the right place:

```
.breadcrumbs a + a::before {
    content: '>';
}
```

Or, as the current page is a `span` you might prefer:

```
.breadcrumbs a::after {
    content: '>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is the same as @David's, but using the single colon syntax, browser support, and removes the annoying link coloring and underlining (Doesn't make the `>` not a link though.

```
.breadcrumbs > a:after{
    content: '>';
    padding-left: 2px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.breadcrumbs > a:link:after{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

### [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/JThomas/k3ZTf/)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I understood the problem better.

**Update 2:** Replacing with matched string, as Bergi suggested.

I came up with the following script that does what you need it to do:

```
jQuery(".breadcrumbs .category").remove();
var resultingHtml = jQuery(".breadcrumbs").html();
resultingHtml = resultingHtml.replace(/(\s*&gt;){2,}/mi, "$1");
jQuery(".breadcrumbs").html(resultingHtml);
```

What this script does is first remove the very last node in breadcrumbs, Then it replace any double (or more) `&gt;` text with a single `gt;`.

You can see it working on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ66F/2/)

Comment: You should replace by `$1`. Your code might insert unwanted whitespaces.

Comment: I was relying on the fact that spaces get dropped in HTML, but I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from [another question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

`$.fn.nextNode = function(){
      var contents = $(this).parent().contents();
      return contents.get(contents.index(this)+1);
    }
    $('.breadcrumbs .category').nextNode().remove();
    $('.breadcrumbs .category').remove();`

Comment: Whoa, that hurts. `$.fn.nextNode = function(){ return this.map(function(){return this.nextSibling;}); };`